# C# WPF Make a Button Randomly Move When Moused Over

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a WPF application using C# and Visual Studio  and I need a button to jump to a random location in the window when the mouse hovers over it. I then need the same thing to happen when you hover over it again. I also don't need an animation, just for it to jump there.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void butNo_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work and is also an animation:

```
<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

Tried this but 'Location' comes with error code CS1061 in VS.

```
private void butNo_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random x = new Random();
        Point pt = new Point(int.Parse(x.Next(200).ToString()), int.Parse(x.Next(250).ToString()));
        butNo.Location = pt;
    }
```

Comment: where is the part where you try to move the button?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?
Also, could you change the margin of the button on the MouseEnter event?

Comment: The part that where I attempted to move the button was in the second code snippet. I found that elsewhere on this website.

Comment: It's for a program I was tasked to make in college where there are 'yes', 'no' and 'maybe' buttons and you need to make the 'no' and 'maybe' buttons move when you mouse over so you can't click them.

Comment: @MeghanArmes It's a relatively well-known prank :o)

Comment: @heltonbiker I mean I like the idea -- I just couldn't get away with it at work most of the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a `Canvas` and animations.

```
<Canvas Name="cnv">
    <Button Name="btn"
            Content="Click Me!"
            IsTabStop="False"
            Canvas.Left="0"
            Canvas.Top="0"
            MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"/>
</Canvas>
```

And the code-behind:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Work out where the button is going to move to.
    double newLeft = rnd.Next(Convert.ToInt32(cnv.ActualWidth - btn.ActualWidth));
    double newTop = rnd.Next(Convert.ToInt32(cnv.ActualHeight - btn.ActualHeight));

    //Create the animations for left and top
    DoubleAnimation animLeft = new DoubleAnimation(Canvas.GetLeft(btn), newLeft, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    DoubleAnimation animTop = new DoubleAnimation(Canvas.GetTop(btn), newTop, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));

    //Set an easing function so the button will quickly move away, then slow down
    //as it reaches its destination.
    animLeft.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
    animTop.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

    //Start the animation.
    btn.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animLeft, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
    btn.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, animTop, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
}
```

And here is a [gif](https://gyazo.com/b639dc341bb9281a993c58b8fcfafe2e) of it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't normally like doing homework problems for people, but I'm bored at work so here you go.

You need to just use the **Margin** and update the Left and Top values to random numbers within the height/width of your grid so it doesn't go outside of the view.

Also, make sure to use **IsTabStop="False"** otherwise, you could tab to it and still click it.

So, for the simplest case using codebehind:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="mousemove.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="button1" Width="75" MouseEnter="button1_MouseEnter" IsTabStop="False"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int maxLeft = Convert.ToInt32(Grid1.ActualWidth - button1.Width);
    int maxTop = Convert.ToInt32(Grid1.ActualHeight - button1.Height);
    Random rand = new Random();
    button1.Margin = new Thickness(rand.Next(maxLeft), rand.Next(maxTop), 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Do we need to re initialise the Random object for every button1_MouseEnter event? or else we can publicly initialise the same object once when the page loads. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: A `Canvas` would be better suited to this problem, as you can make use of `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` methods instead of using a `Margin`.

Comment: Definitely more efficient ways to do this. Since OP obviously didn't have deep knowledge of C#, I just made this as basic as possible with very little code that would work with a new project. Because new projects utilize Grid, I made my solution around that.